# Контактная форма Django - не отправляется письмо

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой, создал контактную форму на Django, но она не отправляет письмо на почту. В чём тут может быть проблема?

Форма:

```
<form role="form" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase"><b>СВЯЗАТЬСЯ С НАМИ</b></h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" aria-label="First_name" name="first_name_form">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия" aria-label="Last_name" name="last_name_form">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" aria-label="Phone_number" name="phone_number_form">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Электронная почта" aria-label="email_adress" name="email_adress_form">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Код из views.py

```
def sending_mails_contacts(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('first_name_form')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name_form')
    email = request.POST.get('email_adress_form')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone_number_form')
    send_mail(subject = email, message = phone, from_email = test@mail.ru, recipient_list = mail@mail.ru, fail_silently=False)
    return redirect('sending_mails_contacts')
return render(request, 'main/contacts.html')
```

Код из settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Из-за чего не приходит письмо на почту? Читал документацию, вроде бы всё сделал по ней. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй это https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/python-django-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-email-c10803c5db36

у тебя к форме подключен токен, но сама форма никак с джанго не связана

```
<form role="form" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase"><b>СВЯЗАТЬСЯ С НАМИ</b></h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" aria-label="First_name" name="first_name_form">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия" aria-label="Last_name" name="last_name_form">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" aria-label="Phone_number" name="phone_number_form">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Электронная почта" aria-label="email_adress" name="email_adress_form">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/696884)

Comment: буду знать, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за эту статью! Почитал, посмотрел, использовал и вроде заработало! Спасибо вам большое!